# SQL Server log file (.ldf) being spammed with LOP_FORMAT_PAGE entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ldf

To start I am new to digging into .ldf entries, I don't even know how to track any of these logs back to the objects creating them, if someone could explain that in their answer it would be appreciated.

Anyways, I have a SQL Server setup with a few databases, and ran into an issue where my hard drive had filled up unexpectedly.

After some searching I found that the log file (`.ldf`) for a database had expanded to immense size (500+ GB), while the database itself is only about 20 GB.

All databases are set for full transactional logging, but only this one database has this problem.

Taking a look at the logs and doing some quick type aggregation, I can see a few things.

1. out of the top 10,000,000 rows in the log file, 55% are `LOP_INSERT_ROW` followed by 11% `LOP_FORMAT_PAGE` and 8% `LOP_LOCK_XACT`
2. Of those `LOP_INSERT_ROW` logs, 52% are `LCX_HEAP` and 46% are `LCX_INDEX_LEAF`
3. The unique thing about this database is it had the generic stored procedures `sys.sp_MScdc_capture_job` and `sys.sp_MScdc_cleanup_job` run on it at one point.

I disabled these jobs weeks ago but the log file is still gaining size rapidly.

How do I track down what's generating all of these log entries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the LOP\_INSERT\_ROWS and LOP\_DELETE\_ROWS operation on a View object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879516/what-is-the-lop-insert-rows-and-lop-delete-rows-operation-on-a-view-object)

Comment: Not at all, My problem is occurring over weeks of time, not a single transaction. I also don't know how to do much of what was done in that article, like digging for the object ID and other identifying information.

Comment: I also need to start a few steps back from where that question starts.
How do I even go about following a transaction log back to the object?